# How to add choices to a field via csom

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to use the Office AMS Core Solution to create choice fields with the possible values.

Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 1, position 133.

The code I am using is:

```
if (!ctx.Web.FieldExistsByName("Rating"))
{
    string xmlChoices = @"<CHOICES>
                        <CHOICE>5</CHOICE>
                        <CHOICE>4</CHOICE>
                        <CHOICE>3</CHOICE>
                        <CHOICE>2</CHOICE>
                        <CHOICE>1</CHOICE>
                      </CHOICES>";
    ctx.Web.CreateField(fieldIdRating, "Rating", FieldType.Choice, "Rating", "Knowledge Transfer Fields", additionalXmlAttributes:xmlChoices);

    Field ratingField= ctx.Web.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Rating");        
}
```

I inspected the XML generated inside the Office AMS Core Solution, and I found that the Choices XML it tries to append it inside the `<Field>`, and not as a child of `<Field>` [as it should be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437580%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this example here using 'AddFieldAsXML'

From: http://sneakydev.blogspot.com/2013/05/using-c-csom-to-interact-with.html

```
Field catField = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(@"
            <Field Type='Choice' DisplayName='Category' Format='Dropdown'>
                <Default>IT</Default>
                <CHOICES>
                  <CHOICE>IT</CHOICE>
                  <CHOICE>Sales</CHOICE>
                </CHOICES>
</Field>", true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
```